# Plupload Response Object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, plupload

I cannot for the life of me figure out why the response object returned by Plupload below cannot be parsed.

Im returning a JsonResult from my ASP.NET MVC controller as follows:

```
    public JsonResult Upload()
    {
        // code to process the upload
        return Json(new { success = true, data = "Some response data" });
    }
```

Im reading it in the view as follows:

```
    uploader.bind("FileUploaded", function (up, file, response) {
        response = $.parseJSON(response);

        alert("I managed to parse it!");

        if (response.success) {
            // do something with the response data
        } else {
            // tell the user there was an error
        }
    });
```

It never gets to the alert "I managed to parse it!"

Comment: Wow posted *44 seconds ago* and answered *44 seconds ago* !!!

Comment: Found the solution while I was transposing my code - thought it might save someone time so posted it anyway :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLVED**

The Plupload FileUploaded event documentation suggests that **the third parameter is a response object. It is infact not!** The response object is contained inside **THAT** object i.e. to see the response data you'd have to do the following:

```
    uploader.bind("FileUploaded", function (up, file, response) {
        alert(response.response);
    });
```

Hope this saves somebody else some time :)